# Allocation information

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In the Bandwidth Summary, How can I get the allocation information(pricing model) using softlayer java API ?

[image: Allocation]

Answer (score 0):

There is no a single API method to return that value, the portal does this:

First it checks to make sure the device has a primary IP address. If it doesn’t the portal displays “N/A” since you can’t have bandwidth without one. If there is a primary IP address it determines what to display as follows:

If the value of the bandwidth allocation is greater than 0 it displays the normal progress bar.
If the value is 0 and the device is a Virtual Guest billed hourly, it displays “Pay As You Go”.
In all other cases it displays “Unlimited”.

Regards

Comment: Thanks.. I think there is "pay as go" for Bare Metal server as well, but it displays "Unlimited" only. In a certain purchasing process, a Baremetal server billed hourly has a Limited Public Bandwidth option only. In this case, allocation is not unlimited.

Comment: It likely are issues.